# Where to start when uploading a SQL Server database to a web server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, t-sql

Here's another question on my lips.

My website uses a database which was created in SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition. Where do I start when I plan to upload the database to the web server? My Website will require this database. Should I send the Scripts which created the database to the Staff of the web server so they can Recreate my database, or should I detach my database and place it in the App Data folder, followed by an update of my Connection strings to reference the detached database?

Another thing I fear is the Database version. Will my Database connection break on the web server because of the "Version of database is 655 and cannot be downgraded to 612" Error? and If yes, How would I prevent that?

Comment: How much control do you have over the web server? Do you use any ORM (such as Linq to SQL)? Are all of your references to the database pointing to an entry in the Web.Config?

Comment: I work for someone who owns a few domains on the web server (my boss) I do not use any Linq, as the webserver which we use doesn't support it. I'm doing straightforward CRUD (System.Data.SQL and System.Data.SQLClient namespaces, SQLConnection object to build the connection to the database, and SQLCommand objects to manipulate and query data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Best way would be to

1: Send them the scripts, let them run it on their side, they should then be able to provide you with server name, database name user id etc.

2: Create a .bak backup file of the database and send that to them and ask them to restore it for you, this way you save a lot of the hassle of creating scripts and you also ensure that the database is like you want it and you know they haven't made a mess of restoring the scripts.

You can also ask them if they don't have some sort of management console where you can upload the database yourself

Comment: Thanks. This information will come in handy. I am still a student though. Was trained to make windows forms applications, and now I'm stuck with asp.net.  :/

Comment: Cool, no worries, always nice helping a fellow saffer :-)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to create a back up of the SQL database, and give that to the web server admin to restore on their server. This will mean that you can guarantee that you will get no problems with the structure, and you should simply have to change the connection string in your Web.Config (assuming that you have always created your connections in code based on the connection string in the web.config), to contain a user name and password that your web server admin gives you (if it's a back up and restore of your db, assuming you use SQL authentication, the new db on the web server will have the same users anyway).

Comment: Thanks for help. Now I know running a backup is a must

Answer (score 1):

Some options;

1. If you have access via Management Studio just use the import/export tools or the Copy Database Wizard
2. If the remote sql server can read from one of the site directories you have access to upload a .bak backup and restore, or upload the database files proper and use one of the sp_attach* procedures
3. Script the database (including data) upload the individual files & create a quick and dirty script that will execute them.

Comment: Thanks for help. Now I know running a backup is a must